# How do I re-enable login on Opensuse Tumbleweed after accidentally disabling login in YAST?

Tags: opensuse

I disabled login in YAST, users, thinking I was enabling auto-login, and now when I get the login window on boot my password is invalid. So I cannot boot Tumbleweed to re-enable login (catch 22). How I can boot into Opensuse?

My system is a Thinkpad X201, with OSs: Opensuse, Antergos, Mint, PClinux, Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from, say, Mint Linux that you have. It just must have a shell.

The following commands should be executed as root.

```
mkdir /mnt_suse
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt_suse
```

- Instead of `sda2` put the name of the partition where Opensuse's root directory is located
  Use `lsblk -f` if it helps

```
$EDITOR /mnt_suse/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
```

- Find the line containing `DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN=""`
  and change it to `DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN="your_user_name"`
  with the intended name instead

```
umount /mnt_suse
rmdir /mnt_suse
```